# How to pass an instance variable from a class to another in odoo

Tags: python, oop, odoo, odoo-15, odoo-16

from odoo import api, models, fields, tools
from odoo.tools.misc import formatLang

class SaleOrder(models.Model):

```
_inherit = 'sale.order'
commission = fields.Float(compute='_compute_commission')
@api.depends('user_id.commission')
def _compute_commission(self):
    for order in self:
        order.commission = order.user_id.commission
```

class AccountTaxGroup(models.Model):

```
_inherit = 'account.tax'
def _prepare_tax_totals(self, base_lines, currency, tax_lines=None):
    res = super()._prepare_tax_totals(base_lines, currency, tax_lines=tax_lines)
    commission_amount = 1900  # Calculate the commission amount here
    res['amount_untaxed'] -= commission_amount
    res['amount_total'] -= commission_amount
    res['formatted_amount_total'] = formatLang(self.env, res['amount_total'], currency_obj=currency)
    print(self.user_id.commission)
    return res
```

---

I want to access value of "commission" declared on "class SaleOrder" inside the "class AccountTaxGroup".
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

for that, you need to open a field of `order_id` so that odoo can know from which record of 'sale.order' you want to take the value of the commission.

```
class AccountTaxGroup(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.tax'

    order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', string='Sale Order')

    def _prepare_tax_totals(self, base_lines, currency, tax_lines=None):
        res = super()._prepare_tax_totals(base_lines, currency, tax_lines=tax_lines)
        commission_amount = 1900  # Calculate the commission amount here
        res['amount_untaxed'] -= commission_amount
        res['amount_total'] -= commission_amount
        res['formatted_amount_total'] = formatLang(self.env, 
        res['amount_total'], currency_obj=currency)
        print(self.user_id.commission)
        sale_order_commission = self.order_id.commission
        print('########', sale_order_commission)
        return res
```

Comment: Thank You. I solved it in another way. Thank you for reply.